# killing the Service class when their eyes stray from my app

Tags: android, service, lifecycle

I have a service class that is not bound to any activity.  Inside of this service class I  am putting a few unfinished audio player components. and there is a Broadcast Receiver there in the from of an anonymous inner class.

there are 5 activities in the application. How do I keep this background Service class alive while the user is navigating between the 5 activity screens.  but kill the service if they navigate outside of these 5?  Like if they leave and look at a different pornography application?

one idea I read about is to bind the service in the onResume() of each Activity and un-bind it in the onPause() of each of the 5 activities.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You need to bind the service like you mention, 

this is a good approach,

Comment: binding and unbinding each activity is good. the issue is that onPause occurs before onResume the next activity, hence you will be having 0 activity bound for a moment. I would unbind in onStop only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each application can also have an `Application` class.

You might want to bind from there and keep track of which activity is open.

Comment: yes, but no, because the application exists as long as activities or services are active.

Comment: Yes that is true. But it exists always, that doesn't mean that you have to be binded all the time